# Maui DependencyService.Resolve Converting from Forms

Tags: dependency-injection, maui

I'm still struggling with probably understanding dependency injection but converting forms code to Maui. I have a class in a pulled in library which gets data and used like 90 times throughout my software and uses my `ICacheManager`.

My old code used:

```
_cacheManager = DependancyService.Resolve<ICacheManager>();
```

Now under new seems like this should be

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<ICacheManager>();
```

But I don't have access to the `Application` in the library where this is coming from since it's a brought into my application. And this doesn't seem to resolve and I get a `NullPointerException`.

To pass around the `ICacheManager` throughout every program needed to pass into my 91 uses of my class would be a ton of work and I thought that's why I did IOC.

How do I replace my one line of code to keep the thing working, or how do I handle this?

Comment: I’m not finding the example, but its possible to inject the service provider as a parameter to app constructor. That will receive the one used by Maui builder. Add to library an Init static method that takes IServices parameter (I might be remembering type wrong), and call that during app startup.

Comment: I can (and do in another instance, but it feels like I'm doing it wrong and not using the methodology the way it was intended.  I may resort to that on this one too.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following official documentation to get more details about [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#introduction-to-dependency-injection).

You could use `var ser = App.Current.MainPage.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IMessageWriter>();` to use your service in the viewmodel.

Step 1. Declare the service interface.

```
public interface IMessageWriter
{
    void Write(string message);
}

public class MessageWriter : IMessageWriter
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MessageWriter.Write(message: \"{message}\")");
    }
}
```

Step 2. Register the Service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageWriter, MessageWriter>();
```

Step 3. Use the Service in a ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ICommand ServiceCommand { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ServiceCommand = new Command(WriteMessage);
    }
    private void WriteMessage()
    {
        var ser = App.Current.MainPage.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<IMessageWriter>();
        ser.Write("message");
    }
}
```